# Using RSLs with Adobe AIR

Tags: apache-flex, memory, actionscript, memory-management, air

Does anyone know how exactly RSLs work with AIR? I have a terminal server that runs several instances of a very large AIR application, which unfortunately has 100M RAM on startup and 200 after a bit of use. This is obviously not really workable, and I'm thinking that RSLs may be a solution if they're cached on the machine. However I haven't been able to find much of anything on this, and I'd really like to know if anyone has.

On a second note, what are some good ways to reduce the initial memory size of an AIR applicaiton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good bit of research, I found that the answer is simply this: Using RSL with Flex gives you the advantage of caching most of the core flex libraries within the browser, thus grossly lowering download speed after that initial one.  This is not, however, the case for AIR. It does you basically no good.

Like james said, it'll help with the DL speed only.

As far as memory goes... check out articles by Grant Skinner - he's helped me out a lot. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

RSLs will only help with download size not RAM usage.  To use less memory I recommend AMF instead of XML as XML parsing has some overhead.

Hope that helps.

-James

Answer (score 1):

Try using the profiler that comes with flexbuilder.  It will help you see what is eating up the memory and then you can change your code accordingly.